# Can't adjust position when button include image

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a dynamic judgment, so i set drawable left by java.
[image]
My problem is, I don't know hot to adjust my image position, I have try to use `android:drawablePadding=""` in xml and `setCompoundDrawablePadding();` in java.

Both of them change my text position not image.

I still try to change `drawable.setBounds()` setting, but it looks like change the proportion not position.

How do i change my image inside the button ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my bttuon.xml:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/goToPersonalPage"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_oval"
            android:text="@string/memberButton"
            android:textColor="#29395e"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
```

and here is my code about button:

```
goToPersonalPage.setCompoundDrawables(setIcon(R.drawable.btn_member_green_128x128), null, null, null);
```

setIcon function is:

```
private Drawable setIcon(int id) {
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.2),
                (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 0.2));

        return drawable;
    }
```

Comment: use padding in your button

Comment: Yes, it looks like the faster way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add   `android:paddingLeft="20dp"` to add left padding for you `Button`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/goToPersonalPage"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_oval"
    android:text="@string/memberButton"
    android:textColor="#29395e"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Use `android:gravity="right"` to change the position of `TextView` .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but paddingLeft will change my text position too.

Comment: Use `android:gravity` and try it .

Comment: Thanks for reply, but gravity can't change my image only text.

Comment: @徐博俊, You can use `android:paddingLeft` to change the position of Image and use `android:gravity` to change the position of `TextView`

Comment: Yes , i try both of them. I test `android:paddingLeft="90"` and `android:gravity="center"` , my button text is not in the middle.

Comment: Because the `android:gravity` was used as the rest of the space of your Button .If you want that your text is in the middle of your Button .You can try to set `paddingRight` of your code .

Answer (score 1):

when you are adding things dynamically then you can Create a **LayoutParams** as follows for the button layout and then set the margin on it and then apply on the button view with `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`.

```
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewGroup = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    viewGroup.setMargins(dimens, dimens, dimens, dimens);
    goToPersonalPage.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
    goToPersonalPage.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_member_green_128x128,0,0,0);
    goToPersonalPage.setLayoutParams(this.viewGroup);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i try your code that let my image and button become more larger.

Comment: you can adjust accordingly setting the margin and padding

Comment: Do you have any suggestion ? I try to `setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100)` or `setMargins(-100, -100, -100, -100)` , i can't see the possible way.

Answer (score 1):

Just add padding that you want to specify-:

```
android:paddingLeft="40dp"

<Button
            android:id="@+id/goToPersonalPage"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_oval"
            android:text="@string/memberButton"
            android:textColor="#29395e"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
```